# inserting postcodes into custom groups in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to come up with an SQL script to insert into Microsoft Visual Studio 2013, in the dataset > Query part under SQL. I have a huge list of postcodes and a custom name denoted to each postcode. For example GL50 4PE is Cheltenham 001A, GL50 4SD is Cheltenham 001B.

I envisaged writing something like:

```
CASE
  WHEN TABLE.ATTRIBUTE IN (GL50 4PE)
THEN 'Cheltenham 001A'
  WHEN TABLE.ATTRIBUTE (GL50 4SD)
THEN 'Cheltenham 001B'
END AS NEWCOLUMNNAME
```

Any ideas please? I would continue to add `WHEN TABLE.ATTRIBUTE IN (GL50 4PE)
THEN 'Cheltenham 001A'` for each postcode I have. I need to do this for lot's of different areas and postcodes and re-run the report once I have this built.

My code in visual studio witht he added part looks like:

```
SELECT        MONTH(HISTORY.DateStart) AS Month, HISTORY.Category_ID,        HISTORY.Learner_ID, NCS.Postcode, Learners_PriorityGroup.PriorityGroup, 
                     YEAR(HISTORY.DateStart) AS Year, HISTORY.DateStart,     HISTORY.HistoryID,
CASE WHEN NCS.POSTCODE IN (GL50 4SD)
THEN 'CHELTENHAM OD1A'
END AS LSOANAME
FROM            NCS INNER JOIN
                     HISTORY ON NCS.Learner_ID = HISTORY.Learner_ID INNER     JOIN
                     Learners_PriorityGroup ON HISTORY.Learner_ID =     Learners_PriorityGroup.Learner_ID
WHERE        (HISTORY.Category_ID IN (479, 480, 481, 482)) AND        (Learners_PriorityGroup.PriorityGroup = 0)
```

Comment: 1) Show your table definition (relevant columns, at least) 2) don't you have a separate column/another entity for the "full names" if there are so many of them? It's a _post code database,_ for God's sake!

Comment: That was very helpful Ivan, NOT!!!!

Comment: It was missing the ' ' around the item and a comma. now it works